# using which mysql_backup packages?

Tags: mysql, .net

I have a DB program and I want to use mysql_backup that is from here:

http://mysqlbackupnet.codeplex.com

When you download the package,there is 3 folders: .Net 2, .Net 4 and .Net 4.5

Is there any difference that which package I use?

Although it's better to use .Net 2 because all my clients have Windows XP that .Net 4 has some crashes on it.

And if there is no difference, then why there is three packages?

thanks

Comment: well what are you using for your program?

Comment: I think that the answer is obvious. You use the version with the same framework version used by your application. If your app uses NET 2.0 then use the version for NET 2.0 and so on...

Comment: for backup and restore and some functions that this .dll supports.

Comment: @Steve your right,but if I can use the version for .net 2, then what is the use of the others???

Comment: If you upgrade your app to use NET 4.0 or 4.5 then....

Comment: I don'n know much about .net but I think if my app runs on .net 4 then it will supports controls and .. that work with .net 2.Is this right???

Answer (score 0):

What "DB program" do you have? I'll take a guess it's MySQL you're working with, but are you using something like Percona or MariaDB as a drop in? Also what flavor of linux are you running on? I only ask because perhaps there are easier/cleaner ways of doing what you are trying to do.

If you have root access to the server you are working with, then why not write a bash script to take care of backing up your databases. Going your own custom route might seem to daunting, but the upside is you get to control how your system backs up. You could get a cron job to make backups to a specific user folder, or even have backups sent to a remote Dropbox. I've got a system similar setup on my own VPS. Happy to help you out if I'm able.

Comment: thanks for your help,but I wrote my app and this works fine, but for other applications I just want to know that why there is several options?is there any difference between them to use???

Comment: What are the different options you are feeling troubled by? Looking at the page you linked each script is written to query the database in standard sql syntax ex "string constring = "server=localhost;user=root;pwd=qwerty;database=test;";" The only exception are the options your program is running.

Comment: I don;t program much in ASP, but I'm in MySQL all the time. The link you posted isn't doing much in terms of being proprietarily extensive.  I'd take the advice given above and stick to the version closest to what you are working with, but in terms of dealing with a database you will be fine.

Comment: sorry dude,I think I did not clarify my question. look,Now I use Mysqlbackup.dll for .net 4. I want to downgrade my application to use .net 3.then I should change mysqlbackup.dll for .net 2. I want to know,if I do this change, will that change cause any problems such decrease speed or sth or not???

Comment: You won't take a hit in terms of your databases. Just make sure to flush your caches. If you are working with vanilla mysql, I'd recommend checking out Percona or MariaDB Mysql drop ins. They can be used to test table integrity and run auto cleanups. Plus you can use their tools to gauge any performance changes.